# Responsive tables not working

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I don't know why the tables are not scalable by device. For example on mobile device I have a scroll but I want the tables to be scalable. Here is my code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <p class="title-table">text</p>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="table-header">txt</th>
        <th class="table-header">txt/th>
        <th class="table-header">txt</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-body-text">
      <tr class="table-bg-light">
        <td>txt</td>
        <td>txt</td>
        <td>stxt</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-bg-dark">
        <td>txt/td>
        <td>1xttttt</td>
        <td>txt</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-bg-light">
        <td>txt</td>
        <td>125dc</td>
        <td>Ptxtxt</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q23c5ckn/
Here is an example with what I want - https://jasonbradley.me/2013/09/05/bootstrap-responsive-tables/

Comment: Put it on jsfiddle.net, we also need your css. So, provide it.

Comment: add image of output at-least

Comment: your are using *Bootstrap* and it has `viewport meta tag` which disable the `user scale`

Comment: Your code is working fine. Add Bootstrap library  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q23c5ckn/

Comment: The code is fine. When in mobile device the table will always have a scrollbar(s).

Comment: So that means is responsive? I want to be scalable..something like on large screen the size of the text to be 1em and to scale by device.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cwL0rszu/1/)

```
.table {
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  word-break: break-word; /* will break word to fit */
}
```

---

If I am getting you correct this is what you require [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cwL0rszu/)

css

```
.table {
  width:100%;
  background:red
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the scroll...I want to be scalable

Comment: Hmm in fiddle works well but when I try to implement on my code won't works.

Comment: Here is an example with what I want - https://jasonbradley.me/2013/09/05/bootstrap-responsive-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Add this tags

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

2.Use media queries.

Example:-

```html
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: try 2nd one ......................................... read 
some good article
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a table responsive.

or

simply add your table's style =

> .table{
>       width:100%;
>       display:block; }

I think it's help you.

Comment: No is not working:( .. Here is an example with what I want - https://jasonbradley.me/2013/09/05/bootstrap-responsive-tables/

Comment: Plz Check your code.. I think you don't link a responsive file in your html file... or simply add media queries in your css..

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have worked it out. Please do let me know if it did work out well.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/q23c5ckn/1/

CSS:

```
table { 
width: 100%; 
border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th { 
background: #333; 
color: white; 
font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
padding: 6px; 
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
{
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
}
thead tr { 
display: none;}

tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

td { 
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
position: relative;
padding-left: 50%;
margin-left: 10px;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;   
}

td:before { 
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
left: 6px;
width: 45%; 
margin-right: 20px;
padding-right: 10px; 
white-space: nowrap;
}

td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "heading 1"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "heading 2"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "heading 3"; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>txt</td>
    <td>txt</td>
    <td>txt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>txt</td>
    <td>txt</td>
    <td>txt</td>
</tr>
```